# Write to a directory that requires root privileges with Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, file-permissions

What is the best solution to write to a directory that requires root privileges without running Visual Studio Code as root?

For example creating a service file in `/etc/systemd/system` with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Really does not seem possible without running vscode as root

Comment: @ArpitSolanki How about an indirect write? I mean write to a directory without root privileges and creating a symlink to the directory that requires it. Can it be considered the best solution or there are other ways??

Comment: Symlinks for root directories does not seem to be a very good idea even though it's possible I don't recommend creating symlinks when you are playing with root directories. Just for curiosity why are not running your vscode as root?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Just avoiding running vs code as root if there is an alternative solution. Can you elaborate more on why creating symlinks to root directories is not recommended. Is there a security issue or what?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/406250/is-it-safe-to-place-symlinks-in-bin-directory it will some what explains the scenario

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Thanks